# Can I make a css div with text "as-is"?

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

Let's assume I have a text like this in the foo.html file:

```html
All the World's a Stage

All the world's a stage,
And all the men and women merely players;
They have their exits and their entrances,
And one man in his time plays many parts,

His acts being seven ages. At first, the infant,
Mewling and puking in the nurse's arms.
Then the whining schoolboy, with his satchel

And shining morning face, creeping like snail
Unwillingly to school. And then the lover,
Sighing like furnace, with a woeful ballad
Made to his mistress' eyebrow.
```

Note the spaces and break lines. Can I put it into a `div` and preserve as it is with css? instead of all text together as it happend when you put into a HTML page:

```
All the World's a Stage All the world's a stage, And all the men and women merely players; They have their exits and their entrances, And one man in his time plays many parts, His acts being seven ages. At first, the infant, Mewling and puking in the nurse's arms. Then the whining schoolboy, with his satchel And shining morning face, creeping like snail Unwillingly to school. And then the lover, Sighing like furnace, with a woeful ballad Made to his mistress' eyebrow.
```

What I want is a behavior very close to `<pre>` tag, I think.

Comment: why not use a pre tag then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `white-space: pre` onto the `div` element.

> Sequences of whitespace are preserved, lines are only broken at newline characters in the source and at <br> elements.

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Answer (score -2):

Hmm.. behavior like a `<pre>`  tag, to do the job a `<pre>` tag does. Perhaps a `<pre>` tag? 
*Only kidding with the sarcasm*

```html
<pre>
All the World's a Stage

All the world's a stage,
And all the men and women merely players;
They have their exits and their entrances,
And one man in his time plays many parts,

His acts being seven ages. At first, the infant,
Mewling and puking in the nurse's arms.
Then the whining schoolboy, with his satchel

And shining morning face, creeping like snail
Unwillingly to school. And then the lover,
Sighing like furnace, with a woeful ballad
Made to his mistress' eyebrow.
</pre>
```

The `<pre>`tag defines preformatted text. Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp).

Are there any reasons why you cannot use this?